# absolutely integrable f with existing non-zero limit at infinity

Tags: real-analysis, limits, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral, infinity

I'm looking for an **example of f(x) which is absolutely integrable but its limit at positive infinity exists and is not zero.**

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx< \infty$$
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)= L\neq 0$$

I know if f'(x) is continuous then the limit at infinity is zero. And there are examples using series where the limit does not exist.

Without considering the existence of f'(x), Is there such function that satisfies the conditions above?

If there is no such function how can I prove it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: No such function exists.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Can you please give me a hint about how to prove there is no such function?

Comment: Suppose $L>0$, and consider a neighborhood of $\infty$ where using properties of the limit, you know that there is some $A\geq 0$ such that for all $x\geq A$, $f(x)\geq L/2$, you can take the integral and obtain that $\int_{A}^B f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \geq (B-A)L/2$. This tends to $\infty$ when $B$ does since $L>0$.

Comment: @M. Boyet Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such functions: $|f(x)| > \frac{L}2$ for $x > x_0$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} | f(x)|dx  \ge \int_{x>x_0} | f(x)|dx  \ge \int_{x>x_0} L dx  = \infty$.

There are integrable functions, such that $\overline{lim}_{x \to \infty} f(x) dx = L > 0$. E.g. $f(x) = \sum_{n \ge 1} I\{ n \le x \le n+2^{-n} \}$.